# How big is the mono runtime?

Tags: mono

How big is the mono runtime, and how does it compare in size to other popular runtimes like python, ruby and java?

Comment: Are you asking about how large the binary files are that compose this runtime, or about how much memory the mono runtime and others take up when a program that uses them is running?

Comment: the binary files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking debian SID and installing the minium required to run a hello world program gives:

RUBY - 13.1 MB

OPENJDK - 137 MB

PYTHON - 17.7 MB

MONO - 11.5 MB

QT - 28.8 MB

This makes Mono the smallest of all languages investigated.

This is taken from blog post by the mono packager directhex.

http://apebox.org/wordpress/rants/416/

Comment: One of the comments points out that if you only install required dependencies, Python is the smallest at 6.1 MB. But apart from Java, there's not a lot of difference between them anyway.